# Regular Expression for a Vehicle Number Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a textbox in asp.net detailsview.
This textbox can only take vehicle number like:

ABG-999 
ATG-9090 
AB-122
B-9999
J-111
880099
88221

Can somebody produce a Regular Expression that i can apply on the textbox? I want the use to only add "-" sign and nothing like a space or a full stop should be allowed.

**EDIT-1**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bowzer_no") %>' ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I don't know what to type in the ValidationExpression to achieve my goal.

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). You've also just given slightly arbitrary examples. Do you have a specification of what your format needs to be?

Comment: sorry about that here is what i am trying <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bowzer_no") %>' ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: @AtharAnis How many chars before `-`? how many digits after `-`?

Comment: @davioooh maximum 3 characters before - and maximum 6 numbers after. Also a vehicle number can comprise of 6-7 numbers only. please have a look at the example above

Comment: can anybody please explain the down vote???

Comment: @AtharAnis I suppose the down-vote is for your `Can somebody produce a Regular Expression?`... You should show what you've tried and ask for support, and not ask for someone to do the work for you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`[0-9]{6,7}|[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,6}`

The first part (before `|`) is for numeric only code (min 6 digits, max 7 digits).
The second part accepts min 1 char, max 3 chars before `-` and min 1 digit, max 6 digits after `-`.

It should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
([a-zA-Z]+-)?\d{3,6}
```

You can tweak the number of digits. My example expects minimum 3, maximum 6.

Comment: that working dradu, but apologies for being poor with regex. It is also allowing aaabbaa-99999, however i want to restrict user to enter maximum 3 Alphanumeric (Optional) in the start, followed by a - sign and then the number. something like ABC-5059

Comment: If you want to limit the letters to max 3, replace the `+` with a `{1,3}`. (one to three letters plus dash, or no letters and no dash)

Comment: sorry @dradu, i can only select one answer as accepted. however, your solution took me 80% towards the goal, while accepted answer worked exactly as i wanted. Thanks for the help anyway